# What POSIX system call can be used instead of forkall on Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris-10

What **POSIX** system call can be used instead of [*forkall()*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2241/forkall-2/index.html) on Solaris 10?

It is possible to use *forkall* on Solaris 10, but how I can determine OS and OS version in preprocessor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forall is not a POSIX system call. Its only available to solaris. It does not have any alternavite in POSIX. You should try to write portable code.

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
..

Comment: Write POSIX code they are implemented on POSIX compliant OSs.

Comment: Ok, what algorithm you can propose in order to copy all parents memory to child?